# Why $\beta_0 \cdot \omega^{\gamma_0} = \omega^{\beta_1} \cdot \omega^{\gamma_0}?$

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation, ordinals

In this [paper](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matlhh/preprints/Baire.pdf), page $12,$ the authors quoted the following:

> For a general nonzero countable ordinal $\beta_0,$ write $\beta_0$ in Cantor normal form as 
>   $$\beta_0 = \omega^{\beta_1}\cdot m_1 + ... + \omega^{\beta_k}\cdot m_k$$
>   where $k,m_1,...,m_k\in\mathbb{N}, \omega_1>\beta_1>\beta_2>...>\beta_k.$
>   If $\gamma_0\neq 0,$ then $\beta_0 \cdot \omega^{\gamma_0} = \omega^{\beta_1} \cdot \omega^{\gamma_0}.$

**Question: How to obtain $\beta_0 \cdot \omega^{\gamma_0} = \omega^{\beta_1} \cdot \omega^{\gamma_0}$?**

I thought it should be 
$$\beta_0\cdot\omega^{\gamma_0} = \omega^{\beta_1} \cdot \omega^{\gamma_0} + ...+\omega^{\beta_k} \cdot \omega^{\gamma_0}.$$

But they look different.

Comment: Your $\omega_0$ is really $\gamma_0$. Think for example of the case $\beta=\omega^2\cdot 2 +3$. What is $\beta\cdot\omega$? Recall that this is just $\beta+\beta+\dots$, the result of concatenating $\omega$ copies of $\beta$. Now, what is $(\omega^2\cdot2+3)+(\omega^2\cdot 2+3)+\dots$? Do you see now how to argue in general?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: I have corrected the typo. But I do not see how to argue in general. Can I have more hints?

Comment: I think i understand now. Since ordinal arithmetic is associative, $2$ and $3$ will be 'absorbed' by $\omega^2,$ leading to $(\omega^2\cdot 2 + 3)\cdot \omega = \omega^3.$

Comment: Perhaps a simpler example would be $(\omega^2\cdot2+3)\cdot2=(\omega^2\cdot2+3)+(\omega^2\cdot2+3)$.  Do all the $2$'s and $3$'s cancel?  (in the case that you multiply be $\omega$, then yes, all the $2$'s and $3$'s will be absorbed)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: The answer to your question is $\omega^2+\omega^2+2+3?$

Comment: No, the $\omega^2$ should be multiplied by $2$, not added at the end.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Oops, I saw your question wrongly, I thought it is $(\omega^2 + 2 +3) + (\omega^2 + 2 +3).$

Comment: So answer is $\omega^2\cdot 4 + 3?$

Comment: Yep lol.  Also, in the question, did you mean to write $\beta_0$ instead of $\beta$?

Comment: Anyways, if you continue with Andrés' hint, you'll find that almost all of the terms will be absorbed by the leading term.

Comment: The distributive law in ordinal arithmetic is one-sided.  A(B+C)-=(AB)+(AC). But (B+C)A may fail to equal (BA)+(BC).... AB is obtained by concatenating B consecutive copies of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been discussed in the comments, the key observation is that for any $\alpha<\omega^{\beta_1}$, $\alpha+\omega^{\beta_1}=\omega^{\beta_1}$.  It follows that \begin{align*}
\beta_0\cdot 2 &= \omega^{\beta_1}\cdot m_1+(\omega^{\beta_2}\cdot m_2+\dots+\omega^{\beta_k}\cdot m_k+\omega^{\beta_1})+\omega^{\beta_1}\cdot(m_1-1)+\omega^{\beta_2}\cdot m_2+\dots+\omega^{\beta_k}\cdot m_k \\
&= \omega^{\beta_1}\cdot m_1+\omega^{\beta_1}+\omega^{\beta_1}\cdot(m_1-1)+\omega^{\beta_2}\cdot m_2+\dots+\omega^{\beta_k}\cdot m_k \\
&= \omega^{\beta_1}\cdot m_1\cdot 2+\omega^{\beta_2}\cdot m_2+\dots+\omega^{\beta_k}\cdot m_k.
\end{align*}

In the same way, we can prove by induction on $\alpha$ that $$\beta_0\cdot\alpha=\omega^{\beta_1}\cdot m_1\cdot\alpha+\omega^{\beta_2}\cdot m_2+\dots+\omega^{\beta_k}\cdot m_k$$ if $\alpha$ is a successor and $$\beta_0\cdot\alpha=\omega^{\beta_1}\cdot m_1\cdot\alpha$$ if $\alpha$ is a limit.  In particular, taking $\alpha=\omega^{\gamma_0}$, we find $$\beta_0\cdot\omega^{\gamma_0}=\omega^{\beta_1}\cdot m_1\cdot \omega^{\gamma_0}=\omega^{\beta_1}\cdot\omega^{\gamma_0}$$ (the latter equality is because $m_1\cdot \omega^{\gamma_0}=\omega^{\gamma_0}$).